# Error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length in R

Tags: r

I am currently trying to test for collinearity amongst my climate raster layers using the 'vifcor' function in R. However I keep getting this error:

```
Error in m[, i] <- getValues(x@layers[[i]]) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

My full R code is as follows:

```
predictors.files <- list.files(path="/Users/josh/Desktop/Predictors/",pattern='asc$',full.names=TRUE)

preds.stack<-stack(predictors.files)
vif(preds.stack)
v1<-vifcor(preds.stack,th=0.7)
```

Then it goes wrong. Can anyone help me with this issue?

The output of `str(preds.stack)`

```
Formal class 'RasterStack' 

[package "raster"] with 11 slots ..@ filename: chr "" ..@ layers :List of 19 .. ..$ :Formal class 'RasterLayer' 

[package "raster"] with 12 slots .. .. .. ..@ file :Formal class '.RasterFile' 

[package "raster"] with 13 slots .. .. .. .. .. ..@ name : chr "/Users/josh/Desktop/Predictors/isothermality.asc" .. .. .. .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S" .. .. .. .. .. ..@ byteorder : chr "little" .. .. .. .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf .. .. .. .. .. ..@ NAchanged : logi FALSE
```

Thanks :)

Comment: check first whats the output of str(preds.stack)?

Comment: This is the first part of the output: Formal class 'RasterStack' [package "raster"] with 11 slots
  ..@ filename: chr ""
  ..@ layers  :List of 19
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ name        : chr "/Users/josh/Desktop/Predictors/isothermality.asc"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE

Comment: its more appropriate if you add the output to your description page above